# Binding jQuery "drop" event to a dropped element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have two tables, trying to pass rows between the tables using draggable and droppable from jquery ui

I am able to drag and drop just fine, however "dropped" elements are not "droppable". As in when I move a row from table 1 to table 2, it works. However if I try to move another row from table 1 to table 2, it will only work if I drop it onto one of the elements that was originally in table 2 when the page loaded. It will not drop onto the elements from table 1 which I have moved over to table 2.

How would I rebind this event, to make a dropped element droppable?

```
$("#inventor tr").draggable({
            helper: "clone",
            start: function(event, ui) {
                c.tr = this;
                c.helper = ui.helper;

            }
    });

var c = {};

    $("#invention tr").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
                    var $row = $(c.tr); 
                    var name = $row.find('td:eq(0)').html();
                    var age = $row.find('td:eq(1)').html();
                    var sex = $row.find('td:eq(2)').html();
                    var group = $row.find('td:eq(3)').html();
                    var pref = $row.find('td:eq(4)').html();



                    var stringToAppend = "<tr><td>"+name+"<span>"+age+" &bull; "+sex+" &bull; "+group+"</span></td></tr>";



             $("#invention table tbody").append(stringToAppend);

          $(c.tr).remove(); //remove from previous
          $(c.helper).remove(); //remove clone
        }
    });
```

Comment: Would it be possible to post some code for us to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be a better idea to bind the `droppable` functionality to the `table` instead of each individual `tr` element. After all, it is the table you're dropping the `tr`s to.